# Crontab command not working

Tags: cron

I know this question has been asked many, many times and I've done a lot of research but still I'm not able to run this extremely simple cron:

```
$ crontab -l
* * * * * /bin/date
```

This should, ideally, print the date every minute.

There is no `cron.allow` or `cron.deny` file, and the `cron` daemon is working:

```
ps -e | grep cron
1119 ?        00:00:00 cron
17646 ?        00:00:00 cron
```

Any idea what might be wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cron processes run in a separate subprocess of their own, so the output of a cron job will not be visible to you in your shell.

Instead, you will have to capture the output of your cron commands and save them. So, set your cronjob like:

```
* * * * * /bin/date >> /home/user/date.log
```

And now, if you will tail this log file, you will start seeing the result.